# Getting the Play Framework to redirect to a Thank You page after file download

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code for the download of a file and then redirecting to a thank you page in the `DownloadController.scala` under the `Play Framework`

```
def thankView = SecuredAction(WithProvider[AuthType](CredentialsProvider.ID)) {
    implicit request: SecuredRequest[DefaultEnv, AnyContent] =>
      Ok(downloadThankView(request.identity))
}




def download = SecuredAction(WithProvider[AuthType](CredentialsProvider.ID)) {

    implicit request: SecuredRequest[DefaultEnv, AnyContent] =>

      val futureMaybeFile = downloadService.generateDownload(request.identity.userID)

      val maybeFile = Await.result(futureMaybeTempFile, 10 second)

      maybeFile match {

        case Some(file) =>

          Ok.sendFile(

            file,

            fileName = _ => Some(file.getName),

            onClose = () => {

              file.delete()

              // position (1) for placing the redirect, which doesn’t prevent the file download, but does not get executed
              Redirect(routes.DownloadController.thankView())

            }
          ).withHeaders(
              "HttpResponse.entity.contentType" -> "text/txt",
              "Content-Disposition" -> s"attachment; filename=${file.getName}"
            )

           // position (2) for placing the redirect which executes but prevents the file download
           Redirect(routes.DownloadController.thankView())
          

        case None =>
          Redirect(routes.InfoController.view(Messages(“oops.there.was.error"), Messages("download.title")))

      }

  }
```

When I place the `Redirect(routes.DownloadController.thankView())` line in the `onClose` section of `sendFile`, it does not get executed; and when it is placed after the `sendFile` it executes but prevents the file from getting downloaded.

What am I missing in here? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

From a HTTP point of view, I think this is not something doable: a single HTTP response cannot contain at the same time a file and be a redirect to somewhere else.

You should rather have some kind of html page that:

1. triggers the file download (via JS for instance)
2. triggers a redirect to the "thank you" page

Comment: Thank you very much. I see why position (2) wasn’t working. Strangely, as far as I remember, this same code with the redirect in the `onClose` section was both downloading and redirecting. Then I changed the code to display the message through some `InfoController` instead and then changed it back to its current state. Now, it doesn’t work.

Comment: So in the `Twirl Engine` can I add a `redirect` action to the download button?

Comment: Sure, I don't know the exact syntax though. This should be documented in Play documentation I guess.

Comment: Do you know the syntax for the `HTML` code of it? I mean I want to trigger two actions by the press of the same button. There is just one problem: The second action should only be executed once and if the first one is successfully finished. So I think doing it server side in the `Play` would be cleaner if I only know the syntax. In the `routes` file, can I change `GET` or `POST` to make it work? Ultimately, I want to sequence two `HTTP` responses or bundle them in a single response.

Comment: IMHO you'll have to deal with that on the client side with JavaScript. You cannot do it only with HTML